# How to make a page's background transparent on Blogger if Soho theme is being used for the blog?

Tags: css, background, blogger, transparent

1. Theres another answer to the same question here, but for another theme.
2. That answer does not work with Soho theme since div classes have been named differently in both.
3. I have tried to figure out which division was concerned, using my browser's developer tools, but failed.

Comment: can you post a code snippet on what you have done

Comment: i did not change anything in the code, but heres the blog: [link](https://knightofvoid.blogspot.in/2018/03/existence.html) and the too-long template code is : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10dGRJYv0riyK1hj6A7gYKefbzY4MUhOk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS :-

```
div.post{
    background-color: white;
}
```

you can use transparent also.

Comment: thx it works and sorry buds for bothering for small questions. i was being lazy. now i am learning css like a good boy :P

Comment: yes i did dat but my reputation is low and so it doesnt make a difference

Comment: If you did it green right tick, people knows my answer is useful for you and my rep is increase and also i get medals of that

Comment: Why does it work when i add the this basic css separately, but not work when i edit the original css given in the template's html under div.post{}. I find this behaviour highly strange

Comment: please check for any new comments on your blog, you might find them interesting. + I have updated my profile